# Click on element inside frame in Puppeteer 1.4.0

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Is there any way to click on an element inside an iFrame in Puppeteer 1.4.0? I think the only way this could work is if it were console javascript run inside `page.evaluate()` as that would work on an outdated version like 1.4.0.

EDIT: When I run the following code (there's only one frame), I get error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null`

```
const frame = await page.frames()[0];
const button = await frame.$('#checkbox');
button.click();
```

Comment: try `const button = await frame.$('#recaptcha-checkbox');`

Comment: That doesn't work but it's closer to the solution than I previously had. Thanks max!

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and i can contribute half way (which i believe is already something).

first we have to capture the frame before trying to access it. And depending on the page load it may be getting null because it hasn't loaded yet. So let's add a wait:

```
await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
```

second we will receive the iframe inside a variable. Let's use some selector, in this case we use the id(#id) and return on screen to visualize:

```
const iframeHandle = await page.$('#IdOfElement')
console.log(`print iframeHandle: ${iframeHandle}`);
```

after that we will receive the content of this frame inside another variable, using the contentFrame() function.
and let's screen print to see if we're getting something or null:

```
const frame = await iframeHandle.contentFrame()
console.log(`printando frame: ${frame}`);
```

And now your return is probably being an

```
[object Object]
```

And as far as I can help because I haven't figured out how to interact with this object yet. hahaha